# Array defining error

Tags: java, arrays

What's wrong with this code?

```
if(a.length >= 2)
    int[] c = new int[]{a[0],a[1]};
return c;
```

It keeps seeming to think that line two of the code above is wrong, in particular, the int[] statement (defining an array). Array a has been defined.

Comment: Proper indentation and bracket usage would have avoided this issue.

Answer (score 7):

The variable `c` exists only in the scope of the `if` block. You can use the `return` right away.

```
if(a.length >= 2)
    return new int[]{a[0], a[1]};
```

Comment: @user2757987 You're welcome. No problem, happens. Consider deleting the question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis He can't now that it's been answered. Moreover, I don't think it was really a dumb question, certainly not as much as some of the other questions that are regularly asked here.

Comment: @arshajii Ah, I didn't know you couldn't after an answer has been posted.

Answer (score 2):

Please use { and }

You have written:

```
if(a.length >= 2)
    int[] c = new int[]{a[0],a[1]};
return c;
```

This means:

int[] c is defined only if your array a has two or more elements.

But you returns always c.

If you use { and }, your code becomes:

```
if(a.length >= 2) {
    int[] c = new int[]{a[0],a[1]};
}
return c;
```

You read better your error.

SOLUTION:

```
int[] c = null;
if(a.length >= 2) {
    c = new int[]{a[0],a[1]};
}
return c;
```

Comment: c is not valid after }

Comment: @dganesh2002: Yes, I've focused my attention on code readable, using {,}. Obviously the int [] c must be placed out of brackets.